# Listen for InfowWindow tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I know it is possible to capture the taps in the infowindow of a marker. [I followed the documentation here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ae1614978aef680d671a6a95da8e13bf7).

All are written in `Objective C` so I tried converting it to `Swift`, here is my code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap InfoWindowOfMarker: GMSMarker) {
        print("You tapped infowindow")

    }
```

But this isn't getting fired at all. What is wrong with the method?

Comment: my apology for late update, now please see the ans it is working  perfect ..

Comment: you are missing to set delegate and i saw there is a `_` mark inside your method which may cause not to execute just check my ans .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use the delegate of `GMSMapView` along with some prior setting see below.

Declare the use of `GMSMapViewDelegate` methods and set the delegate to `self`:

```
class yourClassName: UIViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate

mapView?.delegate = self
```

**Method to detect tap on infoWindow:**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf marker: GMSMarker) {
    print("infowindow tapped")
}
```

**Method to detect tap on `GMSMarker`:**

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    print("tapped on marker")

    if marker.title == "myMarker"{
        print("handle specific marker")
    }
    return true
}
```

**Method to create custom infoWindow:**

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, markerInfoWindow marker: GMSMarker!) -> UIView! {
        let infoWindow = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("nibName", owner: self, options: nil).first as! ClassName
        infoWindow.name.text = "title"
        infoWindow.address.text = "relevant address"
        infoWindow.photo.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")
        return infoWindow
    }
```

Comment: Hello. your code is for a custom infowindow. I am not looking for that. sorry. I am looking for tap event of the infomarker

Comment: then you can work with the marker variable here if you dont need custom window ..